# How do I view the requests submitted to my AWS web service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to set up a web service on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, however whenever I submit a request to the server, it responds with a 404 error.
Is there a way to view a log of the traffic to my AWS server, so I can view whether or not requests are actually being submitted, and whether or not they are properly formed so I may potentially narrow down the origin of the problem?

Comment: What did you search for before posting this question? If I type "view elastic beanstalk logs" into Google this is the first result: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html

Comment: @MarkB I found that, however there are a lot of logs with information that I don't know is relevant. I've searched through a lot of them for instances of my helloworld resource being requested, but can't find any. It's a Java Web Service, if that matters as the documentation says something about application specific logs.

Answer (score 0):

Log for requests sent to the server can be found under:
/var/log/nginx/access.log

You can see a snippet of my log below:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/access.log
-------------------------------------
141.163.107.3 - - [25/Nov/2016:15:50:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2111 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
141.163.107.3 - - [25/Nov/2016:15:51:01 +0000] "GET /HelloWorld HTTP/1.1" 404 490 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
```